# Ensuring that the $sort stage will only hold the number of documents specified in the $limit stage

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

Consider the case where $limit comes immediately after $sort:

```
db.col.aggregate([
  { $match: { } },
  { $sort: { } },
  { $limit: 10 }
])
```

I would assume that in the query above, the `$sort` stage would hold at most 10 documents, and hence RAM is no consideration.

But what if the query has more stages between the `$sort` and `$limit` that may filter out documents:

```
db.col.aggregate([
  { $match: { } } },
  { $sort: { } },

  { $set: { } },
  { $match: { } },

  { $limit: 10 }
])
```

In this query, would it still be possible to have the `$sort` stage to hold no more than 10 documents? If 10 documents make through to the `$limit` stage, then it should able to let the `$sort` stage know, right?

Comment: Sorting will happen everytime a document is inputted to the $sort stage. So if it has 11 documents, then it can safely evict the smallest of them.

Comment: The only way $sort will have 10 documents, is if you apply the limit before it.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor you are wrong. I have manually tested this. I ran query with $sort only and it error out due to exceeding the RAM. I then placed a `$limit: 10` just after the `$sort` and it ran with 100ms without error.

Comment: Combine matches, and move $set to the end: `[{$match:{$and:[condition1, condition2]}}, {$sort:....}, {$limit: 10}, {$set: ...}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each document that has passed through the previous stage of the pipeline, will pass through the next stage in the pipeline. You have two cases, as per the question:

1. When `$sort` and `$limit` are consecutive, in this case, MongoDB only keeps the top `N` sorted documents in the memory, where `N` is the limit. This is why you don't see any memory-based errors here.
2. In your second case, where `$sort` and `$limit` have some stages in between, then this optimization is not possible, as the intermediate stages may alter the output in some unknown manner, like grouping or filtering, etc. Hence you might encounter memory-based issues, because `$sort` tries to keep all the documents in memory.

[$sort documentation.](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#-sort-operator-and-memory)